# Where and how does Thunderbird store email passwords on Linux systems?

Tags: linux, thunderbird

I wish to recover lost a SMTP password, but can't find a recent answer for this question. If it is stored in an sqlite file, observation shows the `/home/$USER/.thunderbird/*.default/*.sqlite` files are mostly encrypted, so in that case, also looking for some insight into the encryption used, and the location of the key needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now, it's stored in `/home/$USER/.thunderbird/$RANDOM_STRING.default-release/logins.json`

I don't know, however, what's the encryption used or the default master password when user didn't set one (maybe it's empty string or some default password hiden in the app code?). I can see it's at least encoded even without setting a master password, but in theory a hacker could probably access it with proper knowledge, so it's basically unprotected. IMO, the Thunderbird devs should start using the login keyring to protect these passwords even when a master password isn't set.

See: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8780/is-it-possible-to-easily-retrieve-thunderbirds-passwords-with-access-to-hdd?newreg=a4029c04cb954aedb4f60a9201574dc7#comment233382_8819

Answer (score 2):

There are [two locations](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird) generally used; please note the {profile name} aka $USER is a random string. and most locations will be a hidden folder, which you can see in your [Nautilus file manager](https://www.lifewire.com/show-hidden-files-folders-ubuntu-files-2205589) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>

/home/$USER/.thunderbird//
/home/$USER/.mozilla-thunderbird/

However, I don't know where the SMTP password would be stored.

**Edit > Preferences > Security > Passwords > Saved Passwords** is normally the command sequence to find the password with most Linus DEs; **Options > Security > Passwords > Saved Passwords > Show Passwords** is the sequence for Windows.

Comment: i'm using thunderbird 52.9.1 (64-bit), those GUI windows you refered to in  linux doesn't exist at least on ubuntu, there isn't edit, but there is humburger button > preferences>security, but there isn't any reference to password.

Comment: Ctrl-H is a Nautilus command; Nautilus is the GUI file manager for your version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the stored passwords from your Thunderbird profile, you can use [this Python script](https://github.com/lclevy/firepwd). It needs the `logins.json` and the `key3.db` or `key4.db` files from the profile directory.

This will list you the passwords from your TB profile:

```
python firepwd.py -d ~/.thunderbird/$Name_Of_Your_Profile_Dir/
```

(It also works for Firefox passwords.)